WooCommerce real-time price add on cart and checkout page
In the API response when some product prices came as zero, all the item's prices were set as zero. I could not find the reason for that.
Also, the order has been created although I have added a checkpoint to prevent that order from being placed.
I have used the below code to calculate real-time for both add and update.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
function before_calculate_totals( $cart_obj ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
       return;
    }


    $logger = wc_get_logger();
    $context = array( 'source' => 'B2BeCONNECT' );

    if(  is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $company_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'parent', true );
        $company_sap_soldto = get_user_meta( $company_id, 'sap_soldto', true );

        $current_url = get_option( 'realtime_price_api_url' );
        $current_url_update = get_option( 'realtime_price_update_api_url' );

        //making array of multiple products
        $sku_a = array();
        $qty_a = array();

        $cart_c = COUNT( $cart_obj->get_cart() );

        $quote_nm = WC()->session->get( 'quote_nm_sap' ) ? WC()->session->get( 'quote_nm_sap' ) : "0";

        $quote_url = ($quote_nm && $quote_nm != "0") ? $current_url_update : $current_url;

        $logger->info('Quote ID'. $quote_nm, $context );
        if ($cart_c < 2) {
            $skuStructure = '';
            foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
                $sku = $value['data']->get_sku();
                $qty = $value['quantity'];
                $skuStructure .= '{    
                  "discount": "",
                  "id": 1,
                  "sku":"' . $sku . '",
                  "qty": ' . $qty . ',
                  "plant": ""
                }';


                $sample_with_quote = '{
                  "productPriceUpdateCollection": {
                  "product_skus": {
                    "item": [' . $skuStructure . ' ]
                  },
                  "customer": {
                    "item": [
                      {
                        "role": "AG",
                        "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
                      },
                      {
                        "role": "WE",
                        "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
                      },
                      {
                        "role": "RE",
                        "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "quote_id": "' . $quote_nm . '",
                  "discounts": {
                    "item": {
                      "type": "",
                      "value": "",
                      "cause": ""
                    }
                  }
                  }
                  }';

            //    $logger->info('Request Body Structure1: '. $sample_with_quote, $context );

                $response = wp_remote_post( $quote_url, array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'timeout' => 240,
                        'redirection' => 5,
                        'httpversion' => '1.0',
                        'blocking' => true,
                        'headers' => array(),
                        'body' => $sample_with_quote,
                        'cookies' => array()
                    )
                );


                if (is_wp_error( $response )) {
                    $logger->info($response->get_error_message(),$context);
                    wc_print_notice( 'Order cannot be processed. Please refresh the page and try again.','error' );
                } else { // Start:If response success


                    $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response['body'], "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA );
                    $json = json_encode( $xml );
                    $array = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

                    if ($quote_nm && $quote_nm != 0) {

                        WC()->session->set( 'quote_nm_sap', $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CHANGE']['ORDER_NUMBER'] );
                        $price_arr = $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CHANGE']['ITEM_OUT'];
                    } else {
                        WC()->session->set( 'quote_nm_sap', $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CREATE']['ORDER_NUMBER'] );
                        $price_arr = $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CREATE']['ITEM_OUT'];
                    }

                  //  $logger->info(wc_print_r( $price_arr), $context );
                    if ($array && !empty( $price_arr )) {
                        $price = $price_arr['ROW']['TOTAL'];
                        $qty = $price_arr['ROW']['QUANTITY'];
                        if ($qty && $price) {
                            $value['data']->set_price( ((float)$price / $qty) );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $value['data']->set_price(0);
                        $logger->info('zero price set', $context );
                    }
                } // End: If response success

            }
        } else {
            foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
                array_push( $sku_a, $value['data']->get_sku() );
                array_push( $qty_a, $value['quantity'] );
            }

            $n = COUNT( $sku_a );
            $i = 1;
            $l = 0;
            $skuStructure = '';
            foreach ($sku_a as $sku) {
                $q = $qty_a[$l] ? $qty_a[$l] : 1;
                if ($i < $n) {
                    $skuStructure .= '{ "discount": " ", "id": 1, "sku":"' . $sku . '", "qty": ' . $q . ', "plant": "" },';
                } else {
                    $skuStructure .= '{ "discount": "", "id": 1, "sku":"' . $sku . '", "qty": ' . $q . ', "plant": "" }';
                }
                $i++;
                $l++;
            }


            $sample_with_quote = '{
          "productPriceUpdateCollection": {
          "product_skus": {
          "item": [' . $skuStructure . ']
          },
          "customer": {
          "item": [
            {
              "role": "AG",
              "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
            },
            {
              "role": "WE",
              "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
            },
            {
              "role": "RE",
              "number": "' . $company_sap_soldto . '"
            }
          ]
          },
          "quote_id": "' . $quote_nm . '",
          "discounts": {
              "item": {
                      "type": "",
                      "value": "",
                      "cause": ""
                    }
                }
            }
          }';

           // $logger->info('Request Body Structure2: '. $sample_with_quote, $context );
            $response = wp_remote_post( $quote_url, array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'timeout' => 240,
                    'redirection' => 5,
                    'httpversion' => '1.0',
                    'blocking' => true,
                    'headers' => array(),
                    'body' => $sample_with_quote,
                    'cookies' => array()
                )
            );

            if (is_wp_error( $response )) {
                $logger->info($response->get_error_message(),$context);
                wc_print_notice( 'Order cannot be processed. Please refresh the page and try again.','error');
            } else { // Start:If response success


                $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response['body'], "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA );
                $json = json_encode( $xml );
                $array = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

                if ($quote_nm && $quote_nm != 0) {
                    WC()->session->set( 'quote_nm_sap', $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CHANGE']['ORDER_NUMBER'] );
                    $price_arr = $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CHANGE']['ITEM_OUT'];
                } else {
                    WC()->session->set( 'quote_nm_sap', $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CREATE']['ORDER_NUMBER'] );
                    $price_arr = $array['Envelopes']['ZSD_SDOC_CREATE']['ITEM_OUT'];
                }
               // $logger->info( wc_print_r( $price_arr, true ), $context );
                $j = 0;
                foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
                    //$logger->info('SKU: '.$value['data']->get_sku(), $context );
                    if ($array && !empty( $price_arr['ROW'] )) {
                        $price = $price_arr['ROW'][$j]['TOTAL'];
                        $qty = $price_arr['ROW'][$j]['QUANTITY'];
                        if ($qty && $price) {
                            $value['data']->set_price( ((float)$price / $qty) );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $value['data']->set_price(0);
                        $logger->info('zero price set', $context );
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
            } // End: If response success

        }
    }
   }

To restrict an order being placed used the below code
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'cancel_order_if_zero_total', 10, 2);
function cancel_order_if_zero_total($order, $data) {

    $cart = WC()->cart;
    $cart_total =round($cart->get_total( 'edit' ) );

    $logger = wc_get_logger();
    $context = array( 'source' => 'B2BeCONNECT' );
    $logger->info( 'Cart total '.$cart->get_total( 'edit' ), $context );

    $customer_id=$cart->get_customer()->id;
    $company = get_user_meta($customer_id,'parent', true);
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key=>$cart_item){
         $product_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
         if( empty($product_price) || $product_price == 0) {
             $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
             $logger->info( 'For Company Id ('.$company.'), Product Id (' . $product_id . ') Price not found. ' . $product_price, $context );
             $error_text = __( "Order cannot be processed. Please refresh the page and try again.", "wocommerce" );
             throw new Exception( $error_text );
         }
    }

    if($cart_total == 0) { // Throw an error notice
        $logger->info( 'For Company Id ('.$company.'), Order total is zero: '.$cart_total, $context );
        $error_text = __("Order cannot be processed. Please refresh the page and try again.", "wocommerce" );
        throw new Exception( $error_text );
    } else {
        return $order;
    }

}


First of all, I would strongly advise you to let go of that absolutely terrible habit of assembling JSON strings "manually". Populate the corresponding data structures instead, and then use json_encode at the end, when you finally need the data in JSON format. For example, $skuStructure .= '{ ... };  executing more than once (which it likely will, since you placed it in a loop), will make "item": [' . $skuStructure . ' ] not be valid JSON any more (because the comma separating the multiple {...} array items from each other, is missing.)
